# What will be the best tree who gives shade and attract birds for boundary wall in Rajasthan's climate

Tags: trees

According to the Rajasthan's climate suggest me about the big tree for vast Boundary wall. Shade and birds are priority. Please give scientific and popular name too.

Comment: If someone gives you the latin name, you can easily find corresponding common names. Why do you ask for both?

Comment: Welcome nishkam sharma!  Can you please post a few pictures showing the area where you want to plant? Also, what is the temperature range where you live? Both of those things are very important for helping you make good choices. Please edit any additional information into the question. To do that, press the grey "edit" word at the bottom. Since you're new here, I invite you to look around the pages of our [help]. They explain the way our site works. If you have questions about how to do anything, just leave a comment and someone will answer you! Have fun here!

Comment: @Sue I didn't ask you, but the OP.